# Questions about pandas: expanding multivalued column, inverting and grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking into pandas to do some simple calculations on NLP and text mining but I couldn't quite grasp how to do them.

Suppose I have the following data frame, relating people's names and their gender:

```
import pandas
people = {'name': ['John Doe', 'Mary Poppins', 'Jane Doe', 'John Cusack'], 'gender': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(people)
```

For all rows I want to:

1. determine the first name
2. determine a list of 3-shingles (sequences of 3 letters contained in a word) deriving from the person name
3. determine, for each shingle, how many males and females contained that shingle on their names.

The goal is to use this as a data set to train a classifier which can determine if a given name is probably a male or a female name.

The first two operations are quite straightforward:

```
def shingles(word, n = 3):
    return [word[i:i + n] for i in range(len(word) - n + 1)]

df['firstname'] = df.name.map(lambda x : x.split()[0])
df['shingles'] = df.firstname.map(shingles)
```

the result is:

```
> print df


  gender          name firstname        shingles
0      M      John Doe      John  ['joh', 'ohn']
1      F  Mary Poppins      Mary  ['mar', 'ary']
2      F      Jane Doe      Jane  ['jan', 'ane']
3      M   John Cusack      John  ['joh', 'ohn']
```

Now, the next step should be done by constructing a new data frame with two columns: gender and shingle, which should contain something like:

```
   gender      shingle 
0       M          joh
1       M          ohn
2       F          mar
3       F          ary
(...)
```

And then I could group by shingle and gender. Ideally, the result would be:

```
   shingle    num_males  num_females 
0      joh            2            0 
1      ohn            2            0 
2      mar            0            1 
3      ary            0            1
(...)
```

Is there an easy way to expand the multivalued column `shingles` in a way that each row produces multiple rows, one for each value found in the list of shingles?

Also, if I `groupby` the column `shingle`, how easy it is to produce different columns with the count for each possible value of the column `gender`?

---

I managed to understand the second part. As an example, to calculate how many males and females for each `firstname`:

```
 def countMaleFemale(df): 
     return pandas.Series({'males': df.gender[df.gender == 'M'].count(), 
                           'females': df.gender[df.gender == 'F'].count()})

grouped = df.groupby('first name')
```

And then:

> print grouped.apply(countMaleFemale)

```
            females  males
first name                
Jane              1      0
John              0      2
Mary              1      0
```

Answer (score 7):

This method should generalize fairly well:

```
In [100]: df
Out[100]:
  gender          name firstname    shingles
0      M      John Doe      John  [Joh, ohn]
1      F  Mary Poppins      Mary  [Mar, ary]
2      F      Jane Doe      Jane  [Jan, ane]
3      M   John Cusack      John  [Joh, ohn]
```

First create an "expanded" series where every entry is a shingle. Here, the index of the series is a multindex where the first level represents the shingle position and the second level represents the index of the original DF:

```
In [103]: s = df.shingles.apply(lambda x: pandas.Series(x)).unstack();
Out[103]:
0  0    Joh
   1    Mar
   2    Jan
   3    Joh
1  0    ohn
   1    ary
   2    ane
   3    ohn
```

Next, we can join the created series into the original dataframe.  You have to reset the index, dropping the shingle position level.  The resulting series has the original index and an entry for each shingle.  Merging this into the original dataframe produces:

```
In [106]: df2 = df.join(pandas.DataFrame(s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True))); df2
Out[106]:
  gender          name firstname    shingles    0
0      M      John Doe      John  [Joh, ohn]  Joh
0      M      John Doe      John  [Joh, ohn]  ohn
1      F  Mary Poppins      Mary  [Mar, ary]  Mar
1      F  Mary Poppins      Mary  [Mar, ary]  ary
2      F      Jane Doe      Jane  [Jan, ane]  Jan
2      F      Jane Doe      Jane  [Jan, ane]  ane
3      M   John Cusack      John  [Joh, ohn]  Joh
3      M   John Cusack      John  [Joh, ohn]  ohn
```

Finally, you can do your groupby operation on Gender, unstack the returned series and fill the NaN's with zeroes:

```
In [124]: df2.groupby(0, sort=False)['gender'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
Out[124]:
     F  M
0
Joh  0  2
ohn  0  2
Mar  1  0
ary  1  0
Jan  1  0
ane  1  0
```

Comment: hummm... nice! I managed to get a solution here but it was a lot more hackish. This is much more elegant. And probably performs better by only using built in methods. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a problem to reproduce this. When I run the your first .unstack() call, I get an AttributeError exception telling me that Int64Index objects has no attribute 'levels'.

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the error?  Where you able to get the toy example working?  I tested it on your toy dataset as well as data that had name lengths longer than 4 and it worked out.

Comment: just a small improvement to the excellent answer: `.apply(lambda x: pandas.Series(x))` can be shortened to `.apply(pandas.Series)`

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to create the expanded version at the time you create `shingles`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050003/pandas-apply-function-to-dataframe-that-can-return-multiple-rows) shows how you can use groupby to do this sort of expansion.  Here's an example of what you can do after creating the "first name" column:

```
def shingles(table, n = 3):
    word = table['first name'].irow(0)
    shingles = [word[i:i + n] for i in range(len(word) - n + 1)]
    cols = {col: table[col].irow(0) for col in table.columns}
    cols['shingle'] = shingles
    return pandas.DataFrame(cols)

>>> df.groupby('name', group_keys=False).apply(shingles)
  first name gender          name shingle
0       Jane      F      Jane Doe     Jan
1       Jane      F      Jane Doe     ane
0       John      M   John Cusack     Joh
1       John      M   John Cusack     ohn
0       John      M      John Doe     Joh
1       John      M      John Doe     ohn
0       Mary      F  Mary Poppins     Mar
1       Mary      F  Mary Poppins     ary
```

(I grouped by name here rather than first name just in case there are duplicate first names, but it assumes the full name is unique.)

From there you should be able to group and count whatever you like.