# How can I create new rows in a pandas data frame containing the words in a string of an existing row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` in `pandas` with a column called `df.strings` with strings of text. I would like to get the individual words of those strings on their own rows with identical values for the other columns. For example if I have 3 strings (and an unrelated column, Time):

```
    Strings Time
0   The dog  4Pm
1  lazy dog  2Pm
2   The fox  1Pm
```

I want new rows containing the words from the string, but with otherwise identical columns

```
Strings   --- Words ---Time  
"The dog" --- "The" --- 4Pm  
"The dog" --- "dog" --- 4Pm  
"lazy dog"--- "lazy"--- 2Pm  
"lazy dog"--- "dog" --- 2Pm  
"The fox" --- "The" --- 1Pm  
"The fox" --- "fox" --- 1Pm
```

I know how to split the words up from the strings:

```
   string_list  = '\n'.join(df.Strings.map(str))
   word_list = re.findall('[a-z]+', Strings)
```

But how can I get these into the dataframe while preserving the index & other variables? I'm using Python 2.7 and pandas 0.10.1.

EDIT:
I now understand how to expand rows using groupby found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050003/pandas-apply-function-to-dataframe-that-can-return-multiple-rows):

```
def f(group):
    row = group.irow(0)
    return DataFrame({'words':  re.findall('[a-z]+',row['Strings'])})
df.groupby('class', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

I would still like to preserve the other columns. Is this possible?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to preserve the index, since the index is supposed to be unique.  For how to expand the values into multiple rows, see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255181/questions-about-pandas-expanding-multivalued-column-inverting-and-grouping/15255472#15255472).

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question and removed the part about the index. Now I'm able to expand the values into multiple rows, but I would still like to preserve the other columns

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my code that doesn't use `groupby()`, I think it's faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({
"strings":["the dog", "lazy dog", "The fox jump"], 
"value":["a","b","c"]})

w = df.strings.str.split()
c = w.map(len)
idx = np.repeat(c.index, c.values)
#words = np.concatenate(w.values)
words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(w.values))
s = pd.Series(words, index=idx)
s.name = "words"
print df.join(s)
```

Thre result:

```
        strings value words
0       the dog     a   the
0       the dog     a   dog
1      lazy dog     b  lazy
1      lazy dog     b   dog
2  The fox jump     c   The
2  The fox jump     c   fox
2  The fox jump     c  jump
```

Comment: Why is `words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(w.values))` preferred to `words = np.concatenate(w.values)`?