# In Pandas, how to find occurrence of one value from one dataframe in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, A (users_df) and B (coffeeA_df) , containing Timestamps in epoch format.
For each Timestamp in A, I need to find whether that same Timestamp (actually, a time window of minus/plus some seconds from the Timestamp) appears somewhere in B.
If it does, I need to extract some values from the row in B and create a new dataframe.
I've done it, and it works, but I used .iterrows() in a nested loop, but as you might imagine, it is very slow and inefficient 
(given the size of my current data set, it takes about 2 hours per file, and I need to process about 100 files).

Is there a faster way of solving this problem making use of Pandas functions/methods?
Any advice would be much appreciated.

**EDIT to include samples of both data frames, and clarify the question regarding time window.**

users_df:

```
   Unnamed: 0    Name       Date       Time               Drink
0           0   User1  14/09/2015  13:15:00  water (hot + cold)
1           1   User2  14/09/2015  13:16:00      Instant coffee
2           2   User3  14/09/2015  16:54:00                 tea
3           3  User2   15/09/2015   9:26:00  coffee + hot water
4           4  User4  15/09/2015   9:43:00          cold water
5           5   User1  15/09/2015  10:11:00          tea + milk
6           6  User5  15/09/2015  10:15:00          cold water
7           7  User4  15/09/2015  11:03:00          cold water
8           8   User1  15/09/2015  11:10:00          cold water
9           9  User4  15/09/2015  11:49:00          cold water
```

coffeeA_df:

```
   Unnamed: 0 NodeID   Coffee          Epoch
0       13334   M002        1  1442241969146
1       13335   M002        1  1442241969648
2       13336   M002        1  1442241970150
3       13337   M002        1  1442241970655
4       13338   M002        1  1442241971156
5       13339   M002        1  1442241971657
6       13340   M002        1  1442241972159
7       13341   M002        1  1442241972663
8       13342   M002        1  1442241973164
9       13343   M002        1  1442241973666
```

Here's my inefficient piece of code:

```
for indexUsers, row in users_df.iterrows():

    #need to convert from String Date/Time into epoch, as coffeeA_df is in epoch
    time_ofAction=users_df.get_value(indexUsers, 'Time')
    day_ofAction=users_df.get_value(indexUsers, 'Date ')
    tStamp=day_ofAction+' ' +time_ofAction

    action_epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(tStamp, pattern)))+DST


    #check for time window in coffee data
    for index, row in coffeeA_df.iterrows():
        time_coffeeA=((coffeeA_df.get_value(index, ' Epoch'))/1000) #normalise epochs to seconds, was in milliseconds

        #check for +- 5 min time window=300 seconds

        if ((time_coffeeA+timeWindow)>=action_epoch ) and ((time_coffeeA-timeWindow)<=action_epoch):
            sensorData = row.copy()

            #obtain desired values from this DF
            sensorData['Activity']=users_df.get_value(indexUsers,'Drink')
            sensorData['User']=users_df.get_value(indexUsers,'Name')
            sensorData['RegisteredActivityTime']=action_epoch

            #append into final DataFrame
            coffeeClean = coffeeClean.append(sensorData, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide a few rows from both dataframes, with at least one matching row?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to include those.

Comment: Also, its not exactly a matching row. Given the nature of the data collection, epochs from the source (coffeeA_df) are collected in milliseconds, whereas user_df's epochs are converted from a string that is in seconds, hence, I need to search from a time window, not a exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to convert to epoch inside the users dataframe:

```
users_df['Epoch'] = users_df['Date'] + ' ' + users_df['Time']
users_df['Epoch'] = users_df['Epoch'].apply(lambda tStamp: int(time.mktime(time.strptime(tStamp, pattern))))
```

Now for a given epoch, you can select the corresponding row with this:

```
time_coffeeA = coffeeA_df['Epoch'].iloc[0] / 1000
users_df[(users_df['Epoch'] - time_coffeeA).abs() < timeWindow]
```

With your example, the output is:

```
    Name        Date      Time Drink       Epoch
2  User3  14/09/2015  16:54:00   tea  1442242440
```

You can now apply this function to the entire coffee dataframe:

```
coffeeA_df.apply(lambda row: users_df[(users_df['Epoch'] - row['Epoch'] / 1000).abs() < timeWindow].iloc[0], axis=1)
```

In case the time window returns multiple rows, I arbitrarily pick the first one, hence the `.iloc[0]` at the end.

Note: I had to use `timeWindow = 500  # not 300` to find a match.

Comment: If as you point out, there are multiple rows, is there a way to get them all and not only the first one as in your solution? thanks!

Comment: I'll have to think about it. I guess you also have cases where there is no matching row, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you try `.unstack()` instead of `.iloc[0]`? This should create additional columns for each matching row.

Comment: To deal with missing columns you could write a proper function instead of a lambda function. It would return null values when the result of the lambda function is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both :)

Comment: Otherwise something along those lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15407768/5276797. First generate the list of all matching rows in `users_df`, then expand them as in the linked answer. Unfortunately I don't have the time to try it myself!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'll give it a go, all that you've already done and told has pointed me in the right direction :)