# How to one-hot encode a dataframe where each row has lists

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to feed in data that has lists within lists of data to a machine learning algorithm:

for example a patient may have several medications and several responses to the medication they may also have names. So if they take more than 1 medication it will come as a list of 2 or more. They only have one name.

I believe one-hot encoding is the correct way to do so.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'drug': ['drugA','drugB'], 'patient': 'john'}, {'drug': ['drugC','drugD'], 'patient': 'angel'}])

             drug patient
0  [drugA, drugB]    john
1  [drugC, drugD]   angel
```

I want to get something like:

```
  drugA  drugB drugC drugD patient
0  1       1     0     0     john
0  0       0     1     1     angel
```

I tried this:

```
pandas.get_dummies(df.apply(pandas.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
```

But got:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing heavily on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277650/2799941), here's one approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'drug': ['drugA','drugB'], 'patient': 'john'}, 
                   {'drug': ['drugC','drugD'], 'patient': 'angel'}])
s = df.drug
      .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
      .unstack()
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)))
        .drop('drug',1)
        .rename(columns={0:'drug'})
df2.merge(pd.get_dummies(df2.drug), left_index=True, right_index=True)
   .drop('drug',1)
```

Output:

```
  patient  drugA  drugB  drugC  drugD
0    john    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0    john    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0
0    john    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0    john    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0
1   angel    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
1   angel    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
1   angel    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
1   angel    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column or omit it and use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- create new `DataFrame` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)
- [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)
- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html)
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('drug').values.tolist()), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
        .groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
print (df1)
   drugA  drugB  drugC  drugD patient
0      1      1      0      0    john
1      0      0      1      1   angel
```

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['drug'].values.tolist()), prefix='', prefix_sep='') \
        .groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df.drop('drug', axis=1)], axis=1)
print (df1)
   drugA  drugB  drugC  drugD patient
0      1      1      0      0    john
1      0      0      1      1   angel
```

---

- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) + [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original

```
df1 = df.pop('drug').astype(str).replace(['\[','\]', "'", "\s+"], '', regex=True)
                .str.get_dummies(',')
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
print (df1)
   drugA  drugB  drugC  drugD patient
0      1      1      0      0    john
1      0      0      1      1   angel
```

```
df1 = df['drug'].astype(str).replace(['\[','\]', "'", "\s+"], '', regex=True)
                .str.get_dummies(',')
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df.drop('drug', axis=1)], axis=1)
print (df1)
   drugA  drugB  drugC  drugD patient
0      1      1      0      0    john
1      0      0      1      1   angel
```