# Pandas Apply(axis=1): produce more than one row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function I want to apply by row like so:

```
def item_split(row):
    items = json.loads(row['items'])
    out = pd.DataFrame([row for i in range(len(items))])
    out['item'] = items
    return out

tweets = tweets.apply(tag_split, axis=1)
```

As you can tell, this function is meant to take a list of items and create a row for each item that duplicates the rest of the remaining data.  Unfortunately, my current method isn't the correct usage of the apply method:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in _asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
   2344                 result = np.empty(len(values), dtype=object)
-> 2345                 result[:] = values
   2346             except ValueError:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (13) into shape (1)
```

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?  I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: Would be able to post some data and your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [pandas: apply function to DataFrame that can return multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13050003/100904) that Wes McKinney [has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052373/100904).

Say your data is like this:

```
In [36]: tweets = pd.DataFrame({
   ....:     'items': [
   ....:         '[{"text": "user1-msg1"},{"text": "user1-msg2"},{"text": "user1-msg3"}]',
   ....:         '[{"text": "user2-msg1"},{"text": "user2-msg2"}]',
   ....:         '[{"text": "user3-msg1"}]',
   ....:     ],
   ....:     'user': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
   ....: })
```

You can use `.groupby()` with `group_keys=False` to return multiple rows per grouped item:

```
In [37]: def item_split(group):
   ....:         row = group.irow(0)
   ....:         result = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(row['items']))
   ....:         result['user'] = row['user']
   ....:         return result
   ....:

In [38]: tweets.groupby('items', group_keys=False).apply(item_split)
Out[38]:
         text   user
0  user1-msg1  user1
1  user1-msg2  user1
2  user1-msg3  user1
0  user2-msg1  user2
1  user2-msg2  user2
0  user3-msg1  user3
```