# Pandas Apply - Return Multiple Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have two data frames and I need to compare the full combinations of rows and return those combinations that meet a criteria. This turns out to be too intensive for our small cluster with `Spark` (using a cross join) so I am experimenting with this approach and **would eventually see if `Dask` can improve on it.**

If table A and B are

```
a=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), columns=['a','b','c'])

b=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[4,7,4],[6,5,1],[8,6,0]]), columns=['d','e','f'])
```

Then all combinations looks like this, where A-D is calculated. Say I want to keep only the rows where A-D >=-3

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   A-D
1   2   3   4   7   4   -3
1   2   3   6   5   1   -5
1   2   3   8   6   0   -7
4   5   6   4   7   4   0
4   5   6   6   5   1   -2
4   5   6   8   6   0   -4
```

I attempted to do this with an apply but it appears I can not return a multi row `dataframe` out of the function (the function creates all the combinations of the single row of 'A' and the entire table of 'B' and returns the rows that meet the criteria.

Here is the function I was testing:

```
def return_prox_branches(a, B, cutthresh):

    aa=a['a']-B['d']

    keep_B = B.copy().loc[(aa.values >= cutthresh),:]

    keep_B['A']=a['a']

    keep_B['B']=a['b']

    keep_B['C']=a['c']

    keep_B['A-D']=a['a']-keep_B['d']

    print(keep_B)

    return(keep_B)



a.apply(return_prox_branches, axis=1, args=(b,-3))





ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 7 to array axis with dimension 1
```

In actuality, these two tables are in the millions of rows.

Is there a way to make this work in pandas efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to pandas DataFrame that can return multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050003/apply-function-to-pandas-dataframe-that-can-return-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Fun Way!

Unpacking in this way became possible in Python 3.5
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#rationale

```
i, j = np.where(np.subtract.outer(a.a, b.d) >= -3)
pd.DataFrame({**a.iloc[i].to_dict('l'), **b.iloc[j].to_dict('l')})

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  7  4
1  4  5  6  4  7  4
2  4  5  6  6  5  1
```

---

### Similar but less confusing

```
i, j = np.where(np.subtract.outer(a.a, b.d) >= -3)
a_ = a.values[i]
b_ = b.values[j]

d = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([a_, b_]),
    columns=a.columns.append(b.columns)
)

d

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  7  4
1  4  5  6  4  7  4
2  4  5  6  6  5  1
```

---

In both cases we depend on an outer subtraction of `b.d` from `a.a`.  This creates a 2-d array of every possible subtractions of values `b.d` from values of `a.a`.  `np.where` finds the coordinates where this difference is `>= -3`.  I can use these results to slice the original data frames and place them together.

---

### Pure(ish) Pandas

I have my doubts you can use this with dask

```
def gen_pseudo(d_):
    def pseudo(d):
        cols = d.columns.append(d_.columns)
        return d_.assign(**d.squeeze()).query('a - d >= -3')[cols]
    return pseudo

a.groupby(level=0).apply(gen_pseudo(b))

     a  b  c  d  e  f
0 0  1  2  3  4  7  4
1 0  4  5  6  4  7  4
  1  4  5  6  6  5  1
```

#### Non-closure alternative

```
def pseudo(d, d_):
    cols = d.columns.append(d_.columns)
    return d_.assign(**d.squeeze()).query('a - d >= -3')[cols]

a.groupby(level=0).apply(pseudo, d_=b)
```

---

### Comprehension

```
ja = a.columns.get_loc('a')
jb = b.columns.get_loc('d')

pd.DataFrame([
    np.append(ra, rb)
    for ra in a.values
    for rb in b.values
    if ra[ja] - rb[jb] >= -3
], columns=a.columns.append(b.columns))

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  7  4
1  4  5  6  4  7  4
2  4  5  6  6  5  1
```

Comment: This is really cool. The only thing is I was hoping to find a pandas method that I could use the Dask drop in for in order to distribute the computation.

Comment: And I am on Python 2.7 :(. I should have mentioned that I see

Comment: The second way is more robust anyway and should work in Python 2.7 (i think).  I'll see if I can think of a pure pandas way for you.

Comment: @B_Miner see if you like that last one.

Comment: Last couple now.

Comment: For the purish pandas solution, is the use of groupby here essentially tricking pandas to allow multiple rows to be returned?

Comment: @B_Miner yes (-:

Comment: If you have one more second - can you explain what that example does :)~. It seems to work....but I dont know why!

Comment: @B_Miner as you correctly surmised, the groupby/apply is a ploy to iterate through rows as if they are single row data frames. It is those data frames that are passed to the function. I know a convenient way to add columns to a data frame via assign and dictionary unpacking. However for that to work I need a series object so I can cal to_dict. But I have a single row data frame. So I use squeeze.

Comment: Is the function within a function required to make this work?

Comment: No!  I just think it's cleaner.  When you use apply, it passes the grouped data frame to the function.  You have a choice, you can have that function use the secondary data frame from the global namespace, pass it as a keyword argument, or use a closure, which is what I did..  I'll add the alternative

Comment: Added the alternative.

Comment: Thank you for....what is a self contained mooc of improving my python/pandas skills!
Now...I wonder if dask works with this :)

Comment: You are welcome.  I'm going to have to invent a reason for me to learn more about dask.