# In pandas apply method, duplicate the row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is an example of my df:

```
pd.DataFrame([["1", "2"], ["1", "2"], ["3", "other_value"]],
                     columns=["a", "b"])
    a   b
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   3   other_value
```

And I want to arrive to this:

```
pd.DataFrame([["1", "2"], ["1", "2"], ["3", "other_value"], ["3", "row_duplicated_with_edits_in_this_column"]],
                     columns=["a", "b"])
    a   b
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   3   other_value
3   3   row_duplicated_with_edits_in_this_column
```

The rule is to use the apply method, do some checks (to keep the example simple I'm not including these checks), but under certain conditions, for some rows in the apply function, duplicate the row, make an edit to the row and insert both rows in the df.

So something like:

```
def f(row):
   if condition:
      row["a"] = 3
   elif condition:
      row["a"] = 4
   elif condition:
      row_duplicated = row.copy()
      row_duplicated["a"] = 5 # I need also this row to be included in the df

   return row
df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I don't want to store the duplicated rows somewhere in my class and add them at the end. I want to do it on the fly.

I've seen this [pandas: apply function to DataFrame that can return multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050003/pandas-apply-function-to-dataframe-that-can-return-multiple-rows/13052373#13052373) but I'm unsure if groupby can help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `df.iterrows` inside a list comprehension. You will need to append your rows to a loop and then concat.

```
def func(row):
   if row['a'] == "3":
        row2 = row.copy()
        # make edits to row2
        return pd.concat([row, row2], axis=1)
   return row

pd.concat([func(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True, axis=1).T

   a            b
0  1            2
1  1            2
2  3  other_value
3  3  other_value
```

I've found that in my case it is better without `ignore_index=True` because I later on merge 2 dfs.

Comment: thanks, this works, would have preferred using apply(), because I use `df.query().apply().combine_first()`, but still with small edits your solution works without having to store the data anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic does seem mostly vectorisable. Since the order of rows in your output appears to be important, you can increment the default `RangeIndex` by 0.5 and then use `sort_index`.

```
def row_appends(x):
    newrows = x.loc[x['a'].isin(['3', '4', '5'])].copy()
    newrows.loc[x['a'] == '3', 'b'] = 10  # make conditional edit
    newrows.loc[x['a'] == '4', 'b'] = 20  # make conditional edit
    newrows.index = newrows.index + 0.5
    return newrows

res = pd.concat([df, df.pipe(row_appends)])\
        .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

   a            b
0  1            2
1  1            2
2  3  other_value
3  3           10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would vectorise it, doing it category by category:

```
df[df_condition_1]["a"] = 3
df[df_condition_2]["a"] = 4

duplicates = df[df_condition_3] # somehow we store it ?     
duplicates["a"] = 5 

#then 
df.join(duplicates, how='outer')
```

Does this solution fit you needs?

Comment: thanks, it would be faster, but yeah my conditions are many and across multiple functions, so this kind of solution will make the code less readable.