# Pandas Dataframe.apply return Dataframe instead of Series

Tags: python, pandas

Code snippet

```
def func(a_val, b_val):
    ...
    return new_df

mydf = mydf.append(existing_df.apply(lambda x: func(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1), ignore_index=True)
```

As per the code snippet shows, I am trying to use apply to iterate over each row in existing_df and return a new_df that need to be append into mydf eventually, but apply only return a Series object and the new_df is converted into a Series where all columns and rows are being throw into 1 single cell after appending into mydf.

Anyway to allow dataframe.apply to return the original dataframe instead?

Update with sample:

```
import pandas as pd

existing_df = pd.DataFrame({'router': ['RouterA', 'RouterA', 'RouterB', 'RouterB'], 'vpn': ['vpn1', 'vpn2', 'vpn3', 'vpn4']})

cols = ['router', 'vpn', 'peer']
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
def func(router, vpn):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    # look for extra information based on router + vpn, and return a dataframe. 1 vpn will return multiple peer result, and the result
    # will need to return back to my_df.
    return new_df

my_df = my_df.append(existing_df.apply(lambda x: func(x['router'], x['vpn']), axis=1))
```

and the new_df should look something like this

```
router  vpn  peer
RouterA vpn1 10.1.1.1
RouterA vpn1 10.1.1.2
RouterA vpn1 10.1.1.3
```

and append into my_df, so each router+vpn will return a multiple rows dataframe and return back to my_df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE (no apply but iterrows)**

**Reason:**
I found similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946771/7035448) requiring multiple rows per apply and found this as working and somehow accepted answer which uses pd.apply (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052373/7035448) does not work for me

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 2, columns=['router', 'vpn'])
cols = ['router', 'vpn', 'peer']
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
def func(row):
    r1 = row['router']
    v1 = row['vpn']
    return pd.DataFrame({'router': [r1, r1, r1], 'vpn': [v1, v1, v1], 'peer': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']})
pd.concat([func(row) 
           for _, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
```

This can be done with itterrows
[image]

---

---

---

Yeah in most use cases I only needed series, but when we need dataframe when there is case like apply needs to return list which is split into columns for example taken from [pd.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), in such cases result_type argument can be helpful.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])

df.apply(lambda x: [1, 2], axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Look at this picture, it should explain
[image]

Above use of argument result_type gives you a dataframe instead of series. Since it is not clear on your func will be done, but from what you described `rows are being throw into 1 single cell`, this should be the way. I guess?

Comment: Update with sample code for you better understanding, but using result_type='expand' doesn't work :(

Comment: @ReverseEngineer can you confirm?